# Remove Overflow in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to remove the overflow warning of the part that cuts the screen.
I am creating a circle and want to cut a section of it.
I want to do something like the image below.

```
   Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50,left: 150),
       //width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

child: Container(
    height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
child: ClipOval( 
child: SomeWidget
)
)
)
```

Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAnTq.jpg

Comment: margin is "outside", padding is "inside". your outer container claims margin of 150dp left of the inner one (which paints the whole screen width), this forces overflow, i think.

Comment: Yes, I want to crop that section that is going out instead of overflow warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `Stack` and `Positioned` widgets like this..

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 150,
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.3,
            child: ClipOval(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```